# Example of a noncommutative, nonunital ring with this property about its ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Is there any noncommutative ring without $1$ that has the following property?

> Every right sided ideal is two sided too, but there exists a left sided ideal that is not two sided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any [right-not-left duo ring](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=84l&L=84r) and take its product with a ring with a zero multiplication ring with $2$ elements.

The result is still right-not-left duo, but the zero ring ensures it does not have identity.